# Angular ui multiselect binding only desired property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angularjs ui select and I want to select more than one items.My code is like this

```
$scope.user.SelectedCategories
$scope.Categories= [
{ value: 'Reading', name: 'Reading Books',Id : 4 },
{ value: 'Sports', name: 'Physical Activity',Id : 9 },
{ value: 'Movies', name: 'Entertainment',Id : 7 },
{ value: 'Video Games', name: 'Passion',Id : 11 }
];

<div class="input-group">
            <ui-select multiple ng-model="user.SelectedCategories" theme="bootstrap" sortable="true" close-on-select="false" style="width: 350px;">
                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Categories...">{{$item.Value}}</ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="category in Categories">
                    {{category.Value}}
                </ui-select-choices>
        </div>
```

Right now SelectedCategories contain the whole object which is selected but I just want to select the Id property of the selected  object.
My desired result is

SelectedCategories = [4,9,11]

but it is

SelectedCategories = [{value:'Reading,name:'Reading Book',Id:4},
                            {value:'Movies',name:'Entertainment',Id:7}]

Comment: Try changing `repeat="category in Categories"` to `repeat="category as category.Id for category in Categories"`

Comment: This is giving an error. Expected expression in form of '_item_ in _collection_[ track by _id_]' but got category as category.Id for category in Categories

Comment: Sorry, it should be `ng-repeat="category.Id as category in Categories"` (Something similar is working for me)

Comment: Alon I upvoted your comment but by mistake it got downvoted and now it is not letting me upvote it again.

Comment: That is totally fine (Upvoting comments does not increase the reputation on Stackoverflow anyway). I am happy for helping, with or without the rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use like

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="category.Id as category in Categories">{{category.Value}}
</ui-select-choices>
```

Comment: It worked like a charm.Thanks a lot shaishab roy and Alon Eitan.

Comment: How can I display selected categories as selected on page reload.Selected categories will be saved in the database and on page reload they will be available on the client side but how can I show them as selected.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module("app", ['ui.select']).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {};
  $scope.user.SelectedCategories=[];
  $scope.Categories = [{
    value: 'Reading',
    name: 'Reading Books',
    Id: 4
  }, {
    value: 'Sports',
    name: 'Physical Activity',
    Id: 9
  }, {
    value: 'Movies',
    name: 'Entertainment',
    Id: 7
  }, {
    value: 'Video Games',
    name: 'Passion',
    Id: 11
  }];

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.16.1/select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.16.1/select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  {{user}}
  <div class="input-group">
    <ui-select multiple ng-model="user.SelectedCategories" theme="bootstrap" sortable="true" close-on-select="false" style="width: 350px;">
      <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Categories...">{{$item.Value}}</ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="category.Id as category in Categories" value="category.Id">
        {{category.value}}
      </ui-select-choices>
  </div>
</div>
```